# How to Assign Random colors to bars in Bar chart in Matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, colorbar, graphing

I am using Matplotlib to graph top customers. I would like for the color of the bar to vary based on the region they are in. Currently I have code that lists each region and assigns a color. Is there are way to iterate through the regions and auto-assign a random color so I don't have redundant code for each region.

#This code block is for the top 15 customers.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20,4))

mask1 = top_cust['region'] == 'South West'
mask2 = top_cust['region'] == 'South East'
mask3 = top_cust['region'] == 'North West'
mask4 = top_cust['region'] == 'West'
mask5 = top_cust['region'] == 'South'
mask6 = top_cust['region'] == 'East'
mask7 = top_cust['region'] == 'North'
mask8 = top_cust['region'] == 'North East'
mask9 = top_cust['region'] == 'Central'

plt.bar((top_cust['customer_name_first'])[mask1], (top_cust['profit'])[mask1], color =   'blue')
plt.bar((top_cust['customer_name_first'])[mask2], (top_cust['profit'])[mask2], color = 'red')
plt.bar((top_cust['customer_name_first'])[mask3], (top_cust['profit'])[mask3], color = 'green')
plt.bar((top_cust['customer_name_first'])[mask4], (top_cust['profit'])[mask4], color = 'black')
plt.bar((top_cust['customer_name_first'])[mask5], (top_cust['profit'])[mask5], color = 'yellow')
plt.bar((top_cust['customer_name_first'])[mask6], (top_cust['profit'])[mask6], color = 'teal')
plt.bar((top_cust['customer_name_first'])[mask7], (top_cust['profit'])[mask7], color = 'grey')
plt.bar((top_cust['customer_name_first'])[mask8], (top_cust['profit'])[mask8], color = 'orange')
plt.bar((top_cust['customer_name_first'])[mask9], (top_cust['profit'])[mask9], color = 'purple')

plt.title('Profits By Customer')
plt.xlabel('Customer')
plt.ylabel('Profits in Dollars')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/), which is a wrapper around matplotlib. In seaborn you can just specify the `hue` parameter like `hue = "region"` to have different colors automatically assigned. Check out [this example](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/grouped_barplot.html) from the seaborn gallery and see if this is what you want.